# WordPress TwentyFifteen submenu items to display when parent/sibling page is active

Tags: wordpress-theming

To improve my WordPress [TwentyFifteen child theme on GitHub](https://github.com/JackDougherty/twentyfifteen-child-theme), I would like submenu items to display when the parent/sibling page is active.

On startup, the menu should remain compact (as it currently does in TwentyFifteen), like this:

- Page 1
- Page 2
- Page 3

When the user opens any top-level page, the menu should auto-expand to reveal submenu items, like this:

- Page 1

  - subpage a
  - subpage b
- Page 2
- Page 3

Currently, these submenu items appear ONLY when the user clicks specifically on the menu down-arrow (a small icon that most users do not see). Instead, my goal is for submenu items to appear whenever the parent page is active.

There are related solutions that address similar issues, but not my issue in Twenty Fifteen:

- https://mpswp.wordpress.com/2015/06/27/twenty-fifteen-theme-reveals-hidden-submenus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS to your stylesheet.

```
.main-navigation ul .current-menu-item ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Hareesh! Your suggestion solved my problem, and I will credit you in my GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words, Jack. Mark this answer as accepted, if your issue is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

@hareesh-sivasubramanian's answer is enough to get the menu displayed but doesn't "tell" Twenty Fifteen that the menu is open. Therefore, to close the submenu, you have to click the toggle button twice!

I fixed this by combining the accepted answer with a small custom jQuery to click the button so that it's toggled:

```
( function( $ ) {

    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $('.main-navigation .nav-menu > .current-menu-item > button').click();
    });

} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: Thanks. Where exactly did you place this additional code?

Comment: It would go in an existing or new JS file, enqueued appropriately from your theme's `functions.php` file. The `$( document ).ready( function() {...` stuff is what actually does the work. The wrapper is just to avoid conflicts in WordPress if this were included as the only thing in the file.

Comment: Thanks again, but since I'm not seeing the "toggle button twice" issue that you describe, and do not see any difference when inserting your code into function.php, I'm going to pass on this. But if I am overlooking something, please refer to my GitHub repo (https://github.com/JackDougherty/twentyfifteen-child-theme) or sample site (https://commons.trincoll.edu/jackdougherty).